# How to get list of banned user in LiveChatBans?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

YouTube provides the ability to ban and unban by liveChatId and channelId.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatBans

But only insert and delete are present, there is no way to get a list of banned channels (list, as in other areas).
In addition, when deleting, you need to use some kind of id, and there is no information on how to compose it yourself or get it through the list.

How to correctly implement a ban, unban and getting a list of banned users in my application?

I have no idea if this is possible.
Google's api is quite powerful, it seems strange that I don't find the obvious.